# Main site + API

Tags: asp.net, api, amazon-web-services

I have a website running on AWS BeanStalk. I have an API (asmx) incorporated into the main code, but I would like to break it out and make it a second project in the same solution (using .Net).

But, how would I go about publishing it? I can only upload the "main site" to Beanstalk. Would I need to set up a second Beanstalk environment to host the API?

Comment: `Project`/`Solution` doesn't necessarily map to "sites". You can "break" up your _code_ according to their function (e.g. web site, api) and still have one "site" (with specific resources/endpoints).

Comment: Sounds good, but did you read the second part of my question? About the second environment?

Comment: If you have separate resources/endpoints/urls for each type of function you want to achieve on a single application, then why have to? In `MVC/WebApi` it's exactly that. The default scaffolding simply designates the `/api` route for `WebApi` endpoints.

Comment: I want to be able to push a new API version without the need to push the entire code base for the "Main site" as well.